# For which values of $t$ is $t T + (1-t) I$ Fredholm, where $T$ is the left shift?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $T$ be left shift, say on $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0})$.  This is Fredholm with $1$ dimensional kernel and $0$ dimensional cokernel, so it has index $1$.  Therefore, $t T + (1-t) I$ cannot be Fredholm for all $t \in [0,1]$.  So for which values of $t$ does this fail to be Fredholm?

Doing this by hand looks time-consuming, so is there a simple way of figuring this out that uses more machinery?

Comment: The set of Fredholm operators is open, so the set in question is an open subset of $[0,1]$.

Comment: @Aweygan I had forgotten this simple fact.  But this fact is not enough to be able to tell where the index changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $t \ne 0$,
$$
            tT+(1-t)I = t\left\{T+\left(\frac{1}{t}-1\right)I\right\}
$$
The spectrum of $T$ is the closed unit disk. Therefore the term in braces on the right is invertible whenever $1/t-1 > 1$ or $1-t > t$ or $1 > 2t$ or $t < 1/2$. This gives an index of $0$ for $tT+(1-t)I$ whenever $0 \le t < 1/2$. And $tT+(1-t)I$ is definitely not invertible for $t > 1/2$, but it is Fredholm. At $t=1/2$, you're looking at the operator $\frac{1}{2}(T+I)$, which is not Fredholm because it doesn't have a closed range.

Comment: Ahh...it's now obvious that many questions of this type boil down to an analysis of the spectrum.

Comment: @A.S. : And I learned from the index why the boundary of the spectrum has to be pathological in this case. I was never quite sure why before this. The Fredholm index is a powerful tool.